# DbDataReader GetIn32 Overflow

Tags: vb.net, sqldatareader

In a current project a `SqlDataReader` is used to receive data from a database query. For convenience reasons, I created the following extension for receiving any integer number:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function GetIntegerNumber(ByVal reader As DbDataReader, ByVal columnName As String) As Byte
    Dim columnNumber = reader.GetOrdinal(columnName)
    Select Case reader.GetFieldType(columnNumber)
        Case GetType(System.Byte)
            Return reader.GetByte(columnNumber)
        Case GetType(System.Int16)
            Return reader.GetInt16(columnNumber)
        Case GetType(System.Int32)
            Return reader.GetInt32(columnNumber)
        Case GetType(System.Int64)
            Return reader.GetInt64(columnNumber)
    End Select
    Throw New ArgumentException($"The column ""{columnName}"" does not contain a value of any integer type.")
End Function
```

For most of the calls the extension works as expected, but for one case it throws a `System.OverflowException`: "The arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow." and I don't understand why.

In the error case, it is called like this: `object.ID = reader.GetIntegerNumber("ObjectID")`,
where `ID` is defined as `Public Property ID() As Integer`. Inspecting the reader,

- `reader.MetaData.metaDataArray(0).metaType.DbType` is `Int32`,
- `reader.MetaData.metaDataArray(0).metaType.SqlType.Name` is `SqlInt32`, and
- `reader._data(0).Int32`, `reader._data(0).SqlInt32` and `reader._data(0).SqlValue` are all `643`.

Using the built-in `reader.GetInt32(0)` function, everything works just fine, no exception. Inspecting the code, this also is the function called by the extension.

In other calls to the extension for setting other `Integer` properties, everything seems to be the same, or at least I couldn't spot a difference. Could somebody help me find out what the problem is? I don't understand this seemingly non-deterministic behavior.

Comment: Your code is trying to return either a `Byte`, `Short`, `Integer` or `Long` and yet your method is declared a returning type `Byte`. Why wouldn't you get an overflow trying to return something bigger than a `Byte` as a `Byte`?

Comment: Your method doesn't really make sense. You'd have to declare the return type as the largest type in order to support all types but then you'll be getting a `Long` value regardless of the actual data type, which is unlikely to be desirable. Basically, you should almost always know what type your data is and use code to get the data as that type. In short, your method is relatively useless.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Assuming you were right, then why does it work in most cases? I'm just doing it that way as VB.net does automatic widening (as described in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1e94s7e.aspx), so the code should be correct?

Comment: It will work for any value that can fit into a `Byte`, regardless of the data type.  That means nothing greater than 255.  Anything greater than that will overflow when you try to put it into a `Byte` because there's too much data to fit.  For that code to even compile, you'd have to have `Option Strict Off` and that's bad to start with.  You should turn `Option Strict On` in the project properties and also the IDE options and leave it `On` except in cases where you specifically need it `Off`, which are very rare. The compiler would spot your mistake and refuse to go further.

Comment: @jmcilhinney You were right, `Option Strict` was set to `Off`. And also I got that article about implicit widening wrong, so thanks for clearing that up for me. You should post your last comment as answer, so I can accept it.